# Virtual host not working AWS apache

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualhost, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have following virtual host ( in apache2.conf file ) to load all subdomain from a single directory on AWS

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ServerName mydevsite.com
   ServerAlias mydevsite.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps
    ServerName mydevsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mydevsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It not working and subdomains are still pointing to html directory

I tried following in htaccess as well but then it gives me 500 error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]
```

My simple requirement is to load main domain from root directory and all subdomains from apps directory

Comment: It's possible that giving both hosts the same `ServerName` may cause an issue. Try using a different name (eg `apps.mydevsite.com`) for the second host.

Comment: @USDMatt but in that case it will point only mentioned host for say apps.mydevsite.com will point to apps folder but other like new.mydevsite.com will not.

Comment: as I didnt try it and as a newbie I am assuming it will work as I explained, correct me if it works other way

Comment: I meant change the `ServerName` directive but keep `ServerAlias *.mydevsite.com`, which should cause that virtual host to be used for all other subdomains.

Answer (score 3):

Your `apache2.conf` has the same `ServerName mydevsite.com` for both vhosts. Apache wants distinct names to identify each virtual host. The configuration could look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydevsite.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apps.mydevsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mydevsite.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/apps"
</VirtualHost>
```

In doubt please read [Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4 - Using Name-based Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html#using).

Before restarting Apache test the configuration:

`$ sudo apache2ctl configtest`

If configtest quits without an error, restart Apache:

`$ sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`